# Why does my code crash when libvlc_media_new_path() is called?

Tags: vlc, libvlc

after several days of trying myself to solve my problem I would like to kindly ask for your help:

I am trying to make the libvlc / SDL 2.0 tutorial working.

I am coding in Visual Studio 2022 in x86 C++ Console.
I have linked the libvlc library path and include path and have added the libvlc.lib file in my project linker settings.

The program compiles without error and crashes when libvlc_media_new_path is called.
You see all different formats of path I have used in my minimal reproducible example below:

My sources:
I downloaded the vlc master from Github to get the headers / include directory.
I downloaded the vlc-3.0.17.4-win32 release and from there took the libvlc.dll.
From the libvlc.dll I created the lib file following a visual studio command prompt procedure.

What i noticed is that the function libvlc_media_new_path() only takes the path as an argument now. All examples i find in the internet are with the libvlc instance AND the path as arguments.

Thank you so much for your help!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "vlc/vlc.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    libvlc_instance_t* libvlc;
    libvlc_media_t* m;
    libvlc_media_player_t* mp;
    
    libvlc = libvlc_new(0, NULL);

    if (NULL == libvlc) {
        printf("LibVLC initialization failure.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
   
    m = libvlc_media_new_path("/1.mp4");

    //m = libvlc_media_new_path("C:\\Programmieren\\PACA\\1.mp4");
    //m = libvlc_media_new_path("C:/Programmieren/PACA/1.mp4");
    //m = libvlc_media_new_path("C://Programmieren//PACA//1.mp4");
    //m = libvlc_media_new_path("C:\Programmieren\PACA\1.mp4");
    //m = libvlc_media_new_path("file:///C:/Programmieren/PACA/1.mp4");
    
    
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(libvlc, m);
   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like the DLL you are using does not match the header file. The DLL probably wants the instance argument. My guess is that you need to get the correct version of the DLL.

Comment: you are confusing libvlc 4 and libvlc 3, the API changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Github and click on the Tags link, you can get the headers for version 3.0.17.4. In there you will see that libvlc_media_new_path takes an instance as an argument.

The other option would be to get or build the 3.0.18 DLL.

Comment: Hi Jim, Thank you so much for the instruction on how to download the correct headers. It solved my problem. Thank you!!!